# Java split String ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException

Tags: java, string, split, indexoutofboundsexception

I have a constructor taking a string which looks like "Southbound - Metrotown".

The string it takes in is always different but has the same format: Direction - Location. I am using the split() method to split this string at the hyphen (unicode 44).

The constructor and return methods looks like this

```
String[] splt;
String dirn;
String plat;

public Arrival(String platform) {
    this.platform = platform;
    splt = platform.split("-");
    dirn = splt[0];
    plat = splt[1];
}
public String getTravelDirn() {
    return dirn.trim();
}
public String getPlatformName() {
    return plat.trim();
}
```

I can print out the results fine but when I test it with JUnit,

```
@Before
public void setUp() {
    arr = new Arrival(platform);
}

@Test
public void testArrivalGetPlatform() {
    System.out.println(arr.getPlatformName());
    assertTrue(arr.getPlatform().equals("Metrotown"));
```

The result prints out Metrotown but the assertTrue line fails. What can I do to fix this? Thank you for your time.

Comment: Try printing argument you are passing to constructor. I suspect that it doesn't have `-` or its `-` is not the same character as you used in your split. Or maybe that error is not related to line `plat = splt[1];` but to some other line which you are not showing us.

Comment: maybe   `splt = platform.split("-");` doesnt split (doesnt have `splt[1]`)?

Comment: try `for(String str : platform.split("-"))` and see what do you get. What is the type of splt ?

Comment: Sorry i forgot to mention. splt, dirn, and plat are all Strings

Comment: how did it compile ? splt should be `String[]` ... no ?

Comment: "splt, dirn, and plat are all Strings" nope, if `platform` is String then `splt` is `String[]` not `String` (that is quite important and you should pay more attention to details in your description - you don't want potential askers to spend their time on things unrelated to your problem, do you?).

Comment: I will ask again. Are you sure that you are passing string containing same `-` you used in your `split("-")`? (notice that there are many characters that look like dash, for instance `- ‒  –  —  ―` are all different dashes witch are indexed in Unicode Table as `45` `8210` `8211` `8212` `8213`. So maybe try iterating over all characters and print their Unicode indexes and compare it with dash you used?

Comment: This code should help you test it `for (char ch : platform.toCharArray()) { System.out.println(ch + ":" + (int) ch);}`.

Comment: I have no problems printing out any of these. The unicode for the dash is 45, which is the same as the one being passed in.

Comment: Are you printing it inside your constructor? If so then maybe that exception is not thrown from `plat = splt[1];` but from some other place which you are not showing us. If you wish to get proper answer you need to provide example which will let us reproduce your problem (also exceptions stack-trace would be nice).

Comment: It would help if you used `assertEquals("Metrotown", arr.getPlatform())` and give us the error message. Also, let us know what value(s) you are testing with. Finally, try using a debugger to see what is going on.

Answer (score 1):

The `platform` parameter value does not have a dash in it.

When no splitting matches are made, the entire string is returned as the first element of a single-element array. Attempting to access any element other than index 0 will cause that exception.

Comment: That is only true if we assume that error comes from line `plat = splt[1];` but to be honest without stack trace we can't be even sure about that. There is also chance that OP is reading some data from source (like some page) which is not using standard dash `-` but some other character, for instance these two dashes are different characters: `‒ –` with codes 44 and 8211.

Comment: Correction: indexes of these dashes ware 8210 and 8211. Is `,` which I used in my code :)